# numpy.append how to use

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to append my numpy array in a loop. In the begining my numpy array is empty.

```
x = np.array([])
```

I would like to append x with 3 element long array in order to get Mx3 matrix, but my array is appending in one dimension... What's wrong?

```
In [166]: x = np.array([])

In [167]: a
Out[167]: array([248, 249, 250])

In [168]: x = np.append(x,a, axis=0)

In [169]: x
Out[169]: array([ 248.,  249.,  250.])

In [170]: x = np.append(x,a, axis=0)

In [171]: x
Out[171]: array([ 248.,  249.,  250.,  248.,  249.,  250.])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
In [51]: x = np.array([])

In [52]: a= np.array([248, 249, 250])

In [53]: x = np.append(x,a, axis=0)

In [54]: np.vstack((x,a))
Out[54]: 
array([[ 248.,  249.,  250.],
       [ 248.,  249.,  250.]])
```

Not sure what way you are using this but I doubt you need to use `np.append(x,a, axis=0)` at all. Just set `x=a` then `vstack`.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but in my opinion it is a workaround. Is it possible to do it only with np.append?

Comment: append works differently in numpy than list.append, it basically concatenates the new and old elements into one array.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that your initial `x` is one-dimensional. See:

```
z = np.array([])
z.shape
# (0,)
np.ndim(z)
# 1
```

So if you `np.append` to `x` you will always end up with a one-dimensional array, i.e. a vector. Note that in Numpy one-dimensional arrays are row-vectors.

To use `np.append` you could start with a 2D array like so. Also, the array you append must have the same number of dimensions as the array you append to.

```
z = np.array([]).reshape((0,3))

a = np.array(248, 249, 250)

a2d = a.reshape(1, 3)
# a2d = np.atleast_2d(a)
# a2d = a[None, :]
# a2d = a[np.newaxis, :]

z = np.append(z, a2d, axis=0)
```